# How to search by tag with the Github Search API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'd like to find all repos with a certain tag and other search criteria with the api, for example all repos with tag `assembly` and docker as free text.

However, the `tag:` prefix, does not work: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tag:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc

Furthermore, searching by tag is not discussed in the doc: https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-code

How to search by tag with the Github Search API?

Comment: For others who arrive here, this is not about `git tags`. Unfortunately this is the page that appears when searching for `github search git tags`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tags are called "topics" for repositories so searching for repositories with a tag is done with the `topic:` syntax.

See: https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-by-topic

Comment: For issues, use label:TAG